# HTTP response after request cancellation

Tags: networking, http, wireshark

I send HTTP request to a server. Server have long running request handler, and after 10 seconds returns 200.
If I cancel a request and immediately send second request, I expect only one response, for second request.
But got also response for first, canceled, request. Why it can occur?

Here is wireshark log of exchange between client 192.168.1.3 and server x.x.x.10

[image]

Packet 21 is first request.
Packet 57 is first request cancelation.
Packet 184 is response for first request. It should not be here! (?)

Comment: note that there is no guarantee that closing the connection will abort server-side processing on the request. the HTTPD may or may not react well to that.

Answer (score 4):

TCP connections are bi-directional, and a single Fin only closes one direction. When you cancelled your request on the client side, you sent a Fin and the server's TCP stack Ack'd it, which confirms that the client-to-server direction is now closed. So it would be illegal for your client to send more data to the server on that connection now. But since the server never sent a Fin, the server-to-client direction is still open. So it's legal for the server to continue to send data on that connection, which it does: the HTTP response.

If you wanted to force both directions closed immediately, you should have sent a TCP Reset (Rst) instead of a Fin.